# Liferay not creating tables in SQL Database

Tags: sql, liferay

I've just created a brand new SQL Server Liferay Database. The database is empty and I'm trying to have Liferay populate it with the proper tables on Tomcat's startup.

I've added the property in my portal-ext.properties to automatically create these tables:

schema.run.enabled=true

However, no tables are getting created and I'm getting the following exceptions:

```
  1dex IX_C1A01806 on Users_Roles (userId);_ [Sanitized]
  213:04:23,941 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "U
  3sers_Teams" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create in
  4dex IX_4D06AD51 on Users_Teams (teamId);_ [Sanitized]
  513:04:23,948 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "U
  6sers_Teams" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create in
  7dex IX_A098EFBF on Users_Teams (userId);_ [Sanitized]
  813:04:23,955 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "U
  9sers_UserGroups" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: crea
 10te index IX_66FF2503 on Users_UserGroups (userGroupId);_ [Sanitized]
 1113:04:23,962 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "U
 12sers_UserGroups" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: crea
 13te index IX_BE8102D6 on Users_UserGroups (userId);_ [Sanitized]
 1413:04:23,970 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "V
 15irtualHost" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create un
 16ique index IX_A083D394 on VirtualHost (companyId, layoutSetId);_ [Sanitized]
 1713:04:23,978 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "V
 18irtualHost" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create un
 19ique index IX_431A3960 on VirtualHost (hostname);_ [Sanitized]
 2013:04:23,985 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 21ebDAVProps" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create un
 22ique index IX_97DFA146 on WebDAVProps (classNameId, classPK);_ [Sanitized]
 2313:04:23,995 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 24ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 25IX_96F07007 on Website (companyId);_ [Sanitized]
 2613:04:24,003 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 27ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 28IX_4F0F0CA7 on Website (companyId, classNameId);_ [Sanitized]
 2913:04:24,010 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 30ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 31IX_F960131C on Website (companyId, classNameId, classPK);_ [Sanitized]
 3213:04:24,017 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 33ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 34IX_1AA07A6D on Website (companyId, classNameId, classPK, primary_);_ [Sanitized]
 35
 3613:04:24,024 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 37ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 38IX_F75690BB on Website (userId);_ [Sanitized]
 3913:04:24,034 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 40ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 41IX_76F15D13 on Website (uuid_);_ [Sanitized]
 4213:04:24,041 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 43ebsite" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 44IX_712BCD35 on Website (uuid_, companyId);_ [Sanitized]
 4513:04:24,051 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 46ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 47 IX_5D6FE3F0 on WikiNode (companyId);_ [Sanitized]
 4813:04:24,073 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 49ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 50 IX_B54332D6 on WikiNode (companyId, status);_ [Sanitized]
 5113:04:24,082 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 52ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 53 IX_B480A672 on WikiNode (groupId);_ [Sanitized]
 5413:04:24,090 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 55ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create uniqu
 56e index IX_920CD8B1 on WikiNode (groupId, name);_ [Sanitized]
 5713:04:24,105 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 58ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 59 IX_23325358 on WikiNode (groupId, status);_ [Sanitized]
 6013:04:24,123 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 61ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 62 IX_6C112D7C on WikiNode (uuid_);_ [Sanitized]
 6313:04:24,135 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 64ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 65 IX_E0E6D12C on WikiNode (uuid_, companyId);_ [Sanitized]
 6613:04:24,143 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 67ikiNode" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create uniqu
 68e index IX_7609B2AE on WikiNode (uuid_, groupId);_ [Sanitized]
 6913:04:24,150 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 70ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 71 IX_A2001730 on WikiPage (format);_ [Sanitized]
 7213:04:24,157 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 73ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 74 IX_16E99B0A on WikiPage (groupId, nodeId, head);_ [Sanitized]
 7513:04:24,164 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 76ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 77 IX_BA72B89A on WikiPage (groupId, nodeId, head, parentTitle, status);_ [Sanitiz
 78ed]
 7913:04:24,170 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 80ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 81 IX_E0092FF0 on WikiPage (groupId, nodeId, head, status);_ [Sanitized]
 8213:04:24,176 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 83ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 84 IX_941E429C on WikiPage (groupId, nodeId, status);_ [Sanitized]
 8513:04:24,183 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 86ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 87 IX_5FF21CE6 on WikiPage (groupId, nodeId, title, head);_ [Sanitized]
 8813:04:24,189 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 89ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 90 IX_CAA451D6 on WikiPage (groupId, userId, nodeId, status);_ [Sanitized]
 9113:04:24,195 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 92ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 93 IX_C8A9C476 on WikiPage (nodeId);_ [Sanitized]
 9413:04:24,200 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 95ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 96 IX_E7F635CA on WikiPage (nodeId, head);_ [Sanitized]
 9713:04:24,206 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
 98ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
 99 IX_65E84AF4 on WikiPage (nodeId, head, parentTitle);_ [Sanitized]
10013:04:24,214 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
101ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
102 IX_9F7655DA on WikiPage (nodeId, head, parentTitle, status);_ [Sanitized]
10313:04:24,220 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
104ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
105 IX_40F94F68 on WikiPage (nodeId, head, redirectTitle, status);_ [Sanitized]
10613:04:24,226 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
107ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
108 IX_432F0AB0 on WikiPage (nodeId, head, status);_ [Sanitized]
10913:04:24,232 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
110ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
111 IX_46EEF3C8 on WikiPage (nodeId, parentTitle);_ [Sanitized]
11213:04:24,238 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
113ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
114 IX_1ECC7656 on WikiPage (nodeId, redirectTitle);_ [Sanitized]
11513:04:24,244 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
116ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
117 IX_546F2D5C on WikiPage (nodeId, status);_ [Sanitized]
11813:04:24,257 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
119ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
120 IX_997EEDD2 on WikiPage (nodeId, title);_ [Sanitized]
12113:04:24,272 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
122ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
123 IX_E745EA26 on WikiPage (nodeId, title, head);_ [Sanitized]
12413:04:24,290 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
125ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
126 IX_BEA33AB8 on WikiPage (nodeId, title, status);_ [Sanitized]
12713:04:24,315 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
128ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create uniqu
129e index IX_3D4AF476 on WikiPage (nodeId, title, version);_ [Sanitized]
13013:04:24,343 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
131ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
132 IX_85E7CC76 on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey);_ [Sanitized]
13313:04:24,586 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
134ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
135 IX_B771D67 on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey, nodeId);_ [Sanitized]
13613:04:24,957 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
137ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
138 IX_E1F55FB on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey, nodeId, head);_ [Sanitized]
13913:04:25,069 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
140ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
141 IX_94D1054D on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey, nodeId, status);_ [Sanitized]
14213:04:25,084 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
143ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create uniqu
144e index IX_2CD67C81 on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey, nodeId, version);_ [Sanitized]
145
14613:04:25,091 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
147ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
148 IX_1725355C on WikiPage (resourcePrimKey, status);_ [Sanitized]
14913:04:25,113 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
150ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
151 IX_FBBE7C96 on WikiPage (userId, nodeId, status);_ [Sanitized]
15213:04:25,119 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
153ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
154 IX_9C0E478F on WikiPage (uuid_);_ [Sanitized]
15513:04:25,126 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
156ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create index
157 IX_5DC4BD39 on WikiPage (uuid_, companyId);_ [Sanitized]
15813:04:25,139 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
159ikiPage" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: create uniqu
160e index IX_899D3DFB on WikiPage (uuid_, groupId);_ [Sanitized]
16113:04:25,147 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
162ikiPageResource" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: crea
163te unique index IX_21277664 on WikiPageResource (nodeId, title);_ [Sanitized]
16413:04:25,166 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
165ikiPageResource" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.: crea
166te index IX_BE898221 on WikiPageResource (uuid_);_ [Sanitized]
16713:04:25,174 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
168orkflowDefinitionLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
169: create index IX_A8B0D276 on WorkflowDefinitionLink (companyId);_ [Sanitized]
17013:04:25,180 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
171orkflowDefinitionLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
172: create index IX_A4DB1F0F on WorkflowDefinitionLink (companyId, workflowDefinit
173ionName, workflowDefinitionVersion);_ [Sanitized]
17413:04:25,196 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
175orkflowDefinitionLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
176: create index IX_B6EE8C9E on WorkflowDefinitionLink (groupId, companyId, classN
177ameId);_ [Sanitized]
17813:04:25,205 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
179orkflowDefinitionLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
180: create index IX_1E5B9905 on WorkflowDefinitionLink (groupId, companyId, classN
181ameId, classPK);_ [Sanitized]
18213:04:25,215 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
183orkflowDefinitionLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
184: create index IX_705B40EE on WorkflowDefinitionLink (groupId, companyId, classN
185ameId, classPK, typePK);_ [Sanitized]
18613:04:25,223 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][BaseDB:457] Cannot find the object "W
187orkflowInstanceLink" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.:
188create index IX_415A7007 on WorkflowInstanceLink (groupId, companyId, classNameI
189d, classPK);_ [Sanitized]
19013:04:25,291 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:288] Invalid
191object name 'Release_'.
19213:04:25,311 WARN  [localhost-startStop-1][ReleaseLocalServiceImpl:288] Invalid
193object name 'Release_'.
19413:04:25,314 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][MainServlet:209] com.liferay.portal.k
195ernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemExceptio
196n: Release_ table was not initialized properly
197com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.ActionException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exce
198ption.SystemException: Release_ table was not initialized properly
199  at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:74)
200   at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.processStartupEvents(MainServlet.ja
201va:1238)
202   at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.init(MainServlet.java:206)
203    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
204   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:
2051266)
206      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.ja
207va:1185)
208      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080
209)
210     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.j
211ava:5027)
212    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.ja
213va:5314)
214    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
215 at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:9
21601)
217      at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
218
219      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
220        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
221
222        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:
2231655)
224   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
225      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
226   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
227     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecuto
228r.java:886)
229  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:
230908)
231      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
232Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException: Release_ table w
233as not initialized properly
234     at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ReleaseLocalServiceImpl.testSupportsStri
235ngCaseSensitiveQuery(ReleaseLocalServiceImpl.java:250)
236       at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.ReleaseLocalServiceImpl.getBuildNumber
237OrCreate(ReleaseLocalServiceImpl.java:185)
238     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
239  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:3
2409)
241        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
242sorImpl.java:25)
243        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
244     at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Servic
245eBeanMethodInvocation.java:115)
246      at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execut
247e(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62)
248 at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(Transact
249ionInterceptor.java:51)
250  at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBe
251anMethodInvocation.java:111)
252      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
253hodAdvice.java:56)
254    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
255BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
256      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
257hodAdvice.java:56)
258    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
259BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
260      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
261hodAdvice.java:56)
262    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
263BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
264      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
265hodAdvice.java:56)
266    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
267BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
268      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
269hodAdvice.java:56)
270    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
271BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
272      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
273hodAdvice.java:56)
274    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
275BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
276      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
277hodAdvice.java:56)
278    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
279BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
280      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
281hodAdvice.java:56)
282    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
283BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
284      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ChainableMethodAdvice.invoke(ChainableMet
285hodAdvice.java:56)
286    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(Service
287BeanMethodInvocation.java:111)
288      at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAop
289Proxy.java:175)
290       at $Proxy77.getBuildNumberOrCreate(Unknown Source)
291      at com.liferay.portal.service.ReleaseLocalServiceUtil.getBuildNumberOrCrea
292te(ReleaseLocalServiceUtil.java:290)
293  at com.liferay.portal.tools.DBUpgrader.upgrade(DBUpgrader.java:102)
294     at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.doRun(StartupAction.java:160)
295        at com.liferay.portal.ee.license.StartupAction.doRun(Unknown Source)
296    at com.liferay.portal.events.StartupAction.run(StartupAction.java:68)
297   ... 20 more
298Stopping the server due to unexpected startup errors
```

Liferay is supposed to autogenerate these tables. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a DDL permission that I did not possess. Once I obtained this I was able to create the tables no problem.

More info on DDL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to restart the MySQL service to solve the error.

1. `sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`
2. `sudo pkill mysqld`

After that, I just went to System Preferences and started the MySQL service from there. Once it started, I ran the server and it worked.